# R Web scraping a website with multiple pages and nested links

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping, nested

I am trying to parse data from a website (http://elsevier.com) and create a data frame out of it. In SO there are similar questions but although very useful do not fit this one. The research pages are articulated as follows: multiple main pages including basic info about the scientific articles/book I want to get and nested pages including the abstract of each article/book. Here's the code:

```
   page_scopus <- 
      paste0(
    "https://www.elsevier.com/search-results?query=%28%28%28%28%28%28%E2%80%98Food%20Supply%E2%80%99%29%20OR%20%E2%80%98Food%20Storage%E2%80%99%29%20OR%20%E2%80%98Hunger%E2%80%99%20OR%20food%20security%20OR%20food%20insecurity%20OR%20household%20food%20security%20OR%20global%20food%20security%29%20OR%20household%20food%20insecurity%29%29%29&page=",
1:1000)

   scrap_scopus <- function(page_scopus) {
   scopus <-
     read_html(page_scopus) %>%
     html_elements(".search-result-text , .search-result-title a") %>%
     map_dfr(
     ~ tibble(
 
     title = .x %>%
      html_element(".search-result-title a") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    authors = .x %>%
      html_element(".book-result-authors , .search-result-meta-item:nth-child(2) strong") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    published = .x %>%
      html_element(".book-result-authors , .search-result-meta-item:nth-child(2) strong") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    ebook = .x %>%
      html_element(".result-detail-list-item:nth-child(1) dd") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    paperback = .x %>%
      html_element(".result-detail-list-item:nth-child(1) dd") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    ISSN = .x %>%
      html_element(".journal-result-issn , img") %>%
      html_text2(),
    
    link = .x %>%
      html_element(".external-link") %>%
      html_attr("href") %>%
      str_c("https://elsevier.com/https://www.elsevier.com", .)
    
  )
)
 get_abstract <- function(link) {
  cat("Scraping:", link, "\n")
  link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("#description div") %>%
  html_text2()
}
scopus %>%
  mutate(abstract = map_chr(link, get_abstract))
}

result_scopus <- map_dfr(page_scopus, scrap_scopus)

 View(result_scopus)
```

Yet, this is the error message I get:

```
Scraping: NA 
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `abstract = map_chr(link, get_abstract)`.
Caused by error:
! 'NA' does not exist in current working directory ('/home/R').
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any hint?

Comment: Did you look at using their API?  Access is free for non-commercial use. https://dev.elsevier.com/

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks. Yes, I have tried but it is complicated to extract a data frame in that fashion (at least for me...)